# Can I combine API/values and API/values/:id in 1 route file?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express

I have this code:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var db = require('../helpers/db');

var data = {
    "word": 1,
    "word2": 2,
    "word3": 3
}

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.send(data);
});



module.exports = router;
```

Whenever I access URL API/values I receive the data in JSON format, however, I would like to add the ability to access API/values/1 and get only the first row of the data variable. Do I need to add a second router.get like that?

```
var express = require('express');
    var router = express.Router();
    var db = require('../helpers/db');

    var data = {
        "word": 1,
        "word2": 2,
        "word3": 3
    }

    router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
        res.send(data);
    });

    router.get('/:id', function(req, res, next) {
        res.send(data);
    });



    module.exports = router;
```

And how exactly can I print only the first row from the JSON variable instead of all 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var db = require('../helpers/db');

var data = {
    "word1": 1,
    "word2": 2,
    "word3": 3
}

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.send(data);
});

router.get('/:id', function(req, res, next) {
    var key = 'word' + req.params.id;
    res.send({ [key]: data[key] });
});

module.exports = router;
```

However I would consider changing your data structure to something more sensible. perhaps the following would be a good start:

```
var data = [
  { word: "1" },
  { word: "2" },
  { word: "3" }
];
```